# How do I change the Support Email of a Firebase Project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

How can I change the support email in my Firebase project under
`Settings` > `Your project` > `Public settings` > `Support email`?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what setting you're referring to, or at least I can't find it in my projects. Can you share  screenshot?

Comment: Weird... I don't see that in the projects I checked. Hopefully somebody else has them and can help.

Answer (score 30):

That setting doesn't show for all project it seems. But when I found it, hovering over the <kbd>?</kbd> says:

> This will be the email address presented to users when they are authenticating with Google. It can be changed to your signed-in email or an email of a Google Group managed by you.

So it looks like you'll need to:

1. Create an email or google group (possibly on your own domain).
2. Add it as a collaborator.
3. Sign in as that collaborator.
4. Select that email address.

Step 3 might not be needed, since I can also see the email addresses of team mates in my test project.

Comment: It seems that Step 3 is a must. When I log in with a project owner email, there is no other option to change the support email. When I log in with the second email/collaborator/project editor, there are two email options for support email.

Comment: After I change the support email to second email and log in the first email again. there are two emails options in the support email. It seems like a minor bug.

Comment: Interesting. I for example can select Abe's email. He's a team mate, and I definitely did not (nor could) sign in as him. Maybe it shows folks who recently signed in? Definitely worth if you'd [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), because if neither of us seems to understand how the list of populated, we're unlikely to be the only ones.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just noticed that what you stated is actually just partially correct. You can add a Google Group email if the signed in Google account owns that group, which is true. For customizable emails, you need to add the email as a member to the project. I proposed an answer including this information.

Comment: I have an [alias setup](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33327?hl=en) support@myapp.app for my main email account. The alias is not showing in Firebase console... I can't use a gmail alias to login. Also, I tried your suggestion of creating a Google Group under the GSuite domain. That Google Group alias I can add to Firebase as a user but still cannot select as a _Support email_. Unfortunately, I cannot login to a Google account with a Google Group alias either. Any creative workarounds? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: @AdamHurwitz have you found a way to setup your alias support@yourapp.app as the support email presented in Google Sign in? I am in the same situation as you and would rather not show my main email account as support...

Comment: @vkammerer, I believe setting up an alias worked for me. See: [_Send emails from a different address or alias_](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)

Comment: I have the same program too. I've add another domain as a secondary domain (NOT ALIAS DOMAIN) on my G suite console. The new domain shows on the firebase console. Actually, you don't need an alias to just receive group emails.

Comment: Step three was what I was missing - thank you so much - i could have never figured that out

Answer (score 19):

To change the **support email**, the email you want to use *needs to be a member of your Firebase project*.

If you need to add a member, you can select the `Add member` option.
In case you want to use a custom domain, you might have to create a new Google account for that email upon accepting the invitation confirmation email.

This will automatically redirect you to the Firebase Console with the new member signed in, but you can also select the email from another member's account.

All steps in a row:

1. Add a member (with your desired email) to your Firebase project *(if you already have that, skip to 4)*.
2. Accept the Firebase invitation *(an email confirmation will be sent to the desired email address)*
3. Create a Google account for that email *(this is an automated process and if that has already been done, you will automatically be redirected to the Firebase Console)*
4. Select the desired email as support email in the `General` settings tab in the Firebase Console using any member's account with sufficient permission.

Comment: May you use a gmail alias? I've created a support@mydomain alias via gSuite I would like to use. However, it does not show up in Firebase after I add the alias as a User to the project.

Comment: @AdamHurwitz Yes, of course. You will have to log into the Firebase project using a Google account that is connected to `support@mydomain`. The activation/invitation email you received from Firebase after adding `support@mydomain` in the console should contain a link, which directs you to Google account creation with that email.

Comment: The above doesn't work if you have a legacy GSuite account, as they only do aliasing, not multi-domain groups; meaning, Firebase ONLY sees the primary domain name for groups. :(

Comment: @tsalaroth You can add any email. Maybe I am having trouble understanding you.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot - if you have a "legacy" G suite account, set up when they were business-only, you're stuck with the domain you have, and you can only add other domains as aliases, not actual mailboxes. meaning you can ONLY select email addresses on the primary domain in that case.

Comment: @tsalaroth, that is correct. I have an [alias setup](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33327?hl=en) for my main email account, not a separate email account. The alias is not showing in Firebase console.

Answer (score 8):

The only thing that worked for me:

1. Add collaborator as OWNER
2. **From the new collaborator account** go to project settings/general and change the support email
3. Go to the original account and change the collaborator account to Viewer or whatever (the support email will remain)

Comment: Thanks, worked for me. How dreadfully unintuitive!

Comment: To change the new member from owner to viewer you need to click their row / name and only then will you see the ability to change their permissions. the 3 dots on the right won't have the option

Answer (score 6):

If you're okay with a Google Groups email there, it's much easier to set up:

1. Go to Google Groups and create a new group there, with you as an owner.
2. Refresh that page and choose the group.

That's it, and there's no need to create or change your account.

Comment: I've created a new group under my Google domain. However, it is not showing under [groups.google.com](https://groups.google.com). Perhaps because the domain group is not public...

Comment: Adding myself as the owner in my domain settings seemed to do the job. Also, it's important to note there might be a few minutes delay for the Firebase console to update.

Comment: This way it shows the google group email address not the members of the group

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem. I bought a domain name and I want to change the **noreply@your-project.firebaseapp.com** for **noreply@my-domain.com**. I followed the next intuitives steps:

- Go to "Authentification" > "Models" > "Email validation" (sorry my firebase service is in french):
  [image]
- Click on the pencil
- Click on "personnalize the domain"
- And then I just followed steps indicated (enter your domain, add DNS entries in your domain service)
- A message at the end will appears and say something like "48 hours may be required to validate your domain".

Ok, let's wait. After 48 hours of waiting, nothing has changed, I still can't custom the email address.

I finally found a solution. Go to "Connection mode":
[image]

- At the bottom of the page, click on "Add a domain" and add your domain (this was the missing step).
- Now you can go back to "Authentification" > "Models" > "Email validation" and change the initial firebaseapp email !

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm stilling waiting for Firebase to recognize my custom domain since there is a 48 hour delay. In the meantime I've used @Oak's solution by creating a **Google Group** and adding myself as the Group Owner. Then, the Group email alias appears in Firebase console after a few minutes delay.

Answer (score 1):

1- Create an email or google group (possibly on your own domain).
2- Add it as a owner to Firebase project.
3- Sign in as that owner.
4- Select that email address.

**Sample image for No.2**

[image]

**Sample image for No.3**

GCP need to **login with same use**r

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use group email from gsuite in Firebase support, you must be the group owner, and do not need that group email address on any IAM role.