# Change Firebase Project Support Email

Tags: firebase

I started a new Firebase Project under my professional email (e.g. `me@mycompany.com`), but this project is for another company, so I want that other company's support email to appear for the users (e.g. `support@othercompany.com`).

Those are the users I have added to the project so far:

[image: Users]

You can see there are 2 users from different emails, those are my emails under different domains (e.g. `me@mycompany.com` and `me@othercompany.com`). Also there's a pending invitation for the support email from that other company (e.g. `support@othercompany.com`). I can't complete that support email invitation because the invitation asks for a Gmail account and that email is a GSuit Business Email Group (which should be valid since Firebase says any Google Group managed by me is acceptable), so I can't make it work.

Now this is the settings where I define the Support Email:

[image: Email]

As you can see there's only one option for one email, my original email.

I can't add the other email or the support Google Group Email.

**How can I set the Firebase Project Support Email as the GSuit Group email?**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682128/how-do-i-change-the-support-email-of-a-firebase-project